# Is the light emitted by an incandescent bulb monochromatic?

Tags: visible-light

Why does an incandescent bulb emit yellow light, and is this light monochromatic? Also, are the different coloured lights produced by coloured disco/party lights monochromatic or not?

Comment: For "classical bulb," do you mean an [incandescent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescence)? If so, answer at link. There are several technologies for disco/party lights.

Answer (score 2):

An ordinary incandescent light bulb emits a broad range of colors, which all blend together to form yellow. The shape of the *spectrum* of this light is that of a black body at a temperature of about 2400 Kelvin, as compared to sunlight which is more nearly white at a temperature of about 5800 Kelvin.

If you put a "disco filter" in front of an incandescent bulb, in each different segment of it you will see a specific band selected out of the whole spectrum which is predominantly one color (red, green, blue, yellow, orange, etc.) but is not perfectly monochromatic the way that, for example, a red LED is.